# How we can deploy my existing kafka - spark - cassandra project to kafka - dataproc -cassandra in google-cloud-platform?

Tags: apache-kafka, cassandra, google-cloud-dataproc, spark-cassandra-connector

My existing project is kafka-spark-cassandra. Now I have got gcp account and have to migrate spark jobs to dataproc. In my existing spark jobs parameters like masterip,memory,cores etc are passed through command line which is triggerd by a linux shell script and create new sparkConf.

val conf = new SparkConf(true)
        .setMaster(master)
        .setAppName("xxxx")
        .setJars(List(path+"/xxxx.jar"))
        .set("spark.executor.memory", memory)
        .set("spark.cores.max",cores)
        .set("spark.scheduler.mode", "FAIR")
        .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", cassandra_ip)

1) How this can configure in dataproc?

2) Wheather there will be any compatibility issue b/w Spark 1.3(existing project) and Spark 1.6 provided by dataproc ? How it can resolve?

3) Is there any other connector needed for dataproc to get connected with Kafka and cassandra? I couldnt find any.

Answer (score 1):

1) When submitting a job, you can specify arguments and properties: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataproc/jobs/submit/spark. When determining which properties to set, keep in mind that Dataproc submits Spark jobs in yarn-client mode.

In general, this means you should avoid specifying `master` directly in code, instead letting it come from the `spark.master` value inside of `spark-defaults.conf`, and then your local setup would have that config set to `local` while Dataproc would automatically have it set to `yarn-client` with the necessary yarn config settings alongside it.

Likewise, keys like `spark.executor.memory`, etc., should make use of Spark's first-class command-line if running `spark-submit` directly:

```
spark-submit --conf spark.executor.memory=42G --conf spark.scheduler.mode=FAIR
```

or if submitting to Dataproc with `gcloud`:

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark \
    --properties spark.executor.memory=42G,spark.scheduler.mode=FAIR
```

You'll also want to look at the equivalent `--jars` flags for jars instead of specifying it in code.

2) When building your project to deploy, ensure you exclude spark (e.g., in maven, mark spark as provided). You may hit compatibility issues, but without knowing all APIs in use, I can't say one way or the other. The simplest way to find out is to bump Spark to 1.6.1 in your build config and see what happens.

In general Spark core is considered GA and should thus be mostly backwards compatible in 1.X versions, but the compatibility guidelines didn't apply yet to subprojects like `mllib` and `SparkSQL`, so if you use those you're more likely to need to recompile against the newer Spark version.

3) Connectors should either be included in a fat jar, specified as --jars, or installed onto the cluster at creation via initialization actions.